# how to solve flutter iOS framework error?

Tags: ios, flutter, error-handling, frameworks

when running app in flutter on iOS simulator I get this error

```
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/_q/npnlj1jx73dbftdw4k23clvm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.laUDdB/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirp6AQZ0/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    ld: framework not found Flutter
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/_q/npnlj1jx73dbftdw4k23clvm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.laUDdB/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirp6AQZ0/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Error (Xcode): Framework not found Flutter

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
Exited
```

I tried flutter clean and flutter pub get but nothing changed

Comment: if there is no changes on the iOS side, I would say to delete iOS folder and run flutter create command to generate iOS folder again.

Comment: there's no changes now this is the error Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase.